# exclude blocks in twig during ajax requests

Tags: ajax, symfony, twig

I have following problem, I have application which is fully operational on ajax and as it has twig for easy maintenance I have one base.html.twig but every time as I include base.html.twig in other pages, the head block

```
{% set page_title = 'Benutzer Dashboard' %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
 <head>
    {% block head %}
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        {% block stylesheets %}
            <link href="{{ asset('css/font-awesome.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
        {% endblock %}
          {% block javascripts %}
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/5b7cf875f5.js"></script>
        {% endblock %}
        <title>{{ page_title }}</title>
    {% endblock %}
</head>
```

is also always being included multiple times in other pages which prevents some jquery code to work normal, my question is, is there any possibility to exclude this block when working with ajax? if ajax doesnt work it should be included but otherwise being excluded.

Comment: create a template for the ajax that extends the base and just override the blocks with empty content

Comment: u mean that when I use jquery ajax, I should fetch another template optimized for ajax requests?

Comment: Yes exactly, easiest way just a create like a `base_ajax.twig` that extends `base.twig` and then extend your ajax calls from `base_ajax.twig`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symfony2, check if an action is called by ajax or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911982#36858984)

Comment: Yeah I know that one, I was just wondering if there's simple way to do it by twig

Comment: @Sparkm4n Not sure what you mean by "do it by twig". I linked the second answer which uses twig, not the accepted answer that does it at the controller level.

Comment: mhm... not the most convenient solution but I might give a try though

Comment: @Sparkm4n To be clear, you put that as your `base.twig`, move your current `base` to `full-layout` that extends `ajax-layout`. This last one defines only `{% block content %}`. No need to change all your templates to include that block verbatim. Maybe a bit convoluted, but I fail to see the inconvenience. Could you elaborate on what kind of solution were you expecting?